# "Unknown column ' ' in 'where clause" error in python-mysql connectivity code

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I want to create an employee attendance system using mysql and python.
After establishing the connection in python I wrote the following code, what I want is that the user enters the date(in format like 31aug20) and a new field named after the date is created.
Then the employee code and name of employee is displayed on the screen and user enters P for present and A for absent.
After running the program a field for a particular date is successfully created but after entering present or absent this error is raised ↓
`-pymysql.err.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'B001' in 'where clause'")`
However, if instead
`+r[0]`
I manually put the ecode, the value is successfully added.

ps. sorry if I was not able to describe my question properly, I am new to stackoverflow.
Following is the code ↓

Thanks

```
def attendance():
  c.execute("select eCode, name from attendance ORDER BY eCode")
  rows = c.fetchall()
  date = input("Enter the date:")
  c.execute("ALTER TABLE attendance ADD "+date+" char(2) NOT NULL")
  db.commit()
  for r in rows:
    print(r, end = '')
    status = input(":")
    if status.upper() == "P":
      c.execute("UPDATE attendance SET "+date+" ='P' WHERE eCode = "+r[0])
```

Comment: Your `eCode` value is `'B001'` - i.e. it is string literal. In the query text it must be quoted with single qoutes whereas you concatenate it without them, and non-quoted value is treated as column name. Use `c.execute("UPDATE attendance SET "+date+" ='P' WHERE eCode = '"+r[0]+"'")`. *However, if instead +r[0] I manually put the ecode, the value is successfully added.* You add the ecode in quoted form, is it?

Comment: Also i would add to re-consider your database design as it is a bad idea to use a DDL statement (`Alter`) daily. You can add a date column and insert rows for each date.

Comment: @Akina Yes, I did add the eCode in quotes. And Thank you so much, it is working now!!

Comment: @CaffeinatedCod3r Thank you so much for suggesting that, I am just doing that now!!